# how to use mod_rewrite in joomla backend

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator, .htaccess-configuration

how i can change the displayed address

```
administrator/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&layout=edit
```

to

```
administrator/content/article/edit
```

by using htaccess file in joomla

Comment: The backend doesn't use SEF URL's as there's absolutely no reason to do so. Why would you want to do this anyway?

Comment: it seems dirty,i know it's not important to have SEF URL's in backend but i like to have better URL's